# how to advanced select on MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, select

i have table category the format is like this

```
|id|parent_id|name|  
|1 |0        |sport|  
|2 |0        |music|
|3 |1        |Stadium|
|4 |1        |Golf| 
|5 |2        |Theater|
|6 |2        |Cinema|
```

**Desc**

`parent_id = 0` is Main category

`parent_id != 0` is Sub category and the main Category is Parent_id

and this is the table users

```
|id|name|category_id|
|1 |andrea|6        |
|2 |Michael | 5     |
|3 |Gorchuf | 1     |
```

**The Problem**

selection Category that is Include on Users table and showing only main category example the goal will be like this

```
|id|name|total|
|1 |sport |1  |
|2 |music |2  |
```

i'm try with this query

```
SELECT C.id C.name, count( U.category_id ) AS total
FROM categories C
LEFT JOIN users U ON ( U.category_id = C.id )
GROUP BY C.id
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

but the result is include sub category and main category

```
|id|name|total|
|1 |cinema |1 |
|2 |theater|1 |
|3 |sport  |1 |
```

How can I filter that only main category?

Comment: still not clear exactly what you want to achieve. Can you give some detail what u explain in "selection Category that is Include on Users table and showing only main category example the goal will bw like this"

Comment: i just want to select category only main category and count that by including sub category...:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QUERY:

**[SQLFiddleExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4dc6c/18)**

```
SELECT c.id, c.name,
(SELECT  count(u.id)
 FROM users u
  LEFT JOIN categories c1
    ON u.category_id = c1.id
  WHERE CASE WHEN c1.parent_id = 0 
             THEN c1.id
             ELSE c1.parent_id 
        END = c.id) AS total
FROM categories c
WHERE c.parent_id = 0
GROUP BY c.id
```

Result:

```
| ID |  NAME | TOTAL |
----------------------
|  1 | sport |     1 |
|  2 | music |     2 |
```

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your problem--

```
SELECT pc . * , (SELECT count( * ) FROM category  AS pc1 WHERE pc.id = pc1.parent_id) AS CNT
FROM `category` AS pc
WHERE `parent_id` =0
```